# Showing line execution count in Xcode

Tags: xcode, code-coverage

Does anyone know if it is possible to highlight line execution count in Xcode as in the following screeshot

[image: Line execution count]

Line execution count may be found on the right side.
Xcode highlights line execution count automatically when you run tests on a scheme with `gather coverage data` option turned on.

However, if you run tests from a shell script, line execution count is not highlighted. I use [xcov-core](https://github.com/nakiostudio/xcov-core) tool to parse `.xccoverage` files into `.json`. This `.json` does not contain line execution count by default. I added this feature in my fork of the repo.

I know how to highlight errors and warnings in Xcode:
`echo {full_path_to_file}{:line}{:character}: {error,warning}: {content}`

I'm looking for a similar way of highlighting line execution count.

Thanks in advance